# MySQL CASE Statement in SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query question. I built a table that keeps track of high school football scores. It looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `games` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `home_team` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `visitor_team` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `home_score` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `visitor_score` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `quarter` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `week` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `game_date` date NOT NULL,
  `game_time` time NOT NULL,
  `complete` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `stadium_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=151;
```

The query that I am doing uses a team's id to compare with. I want to retrieve the id values of the teams that the given team id defeated only. Here is my query so far.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN games.home_team != ? AND (games.home_score > games.visitor_score) THEN games.home_team 
        WHEN games.visitor_team != ? AND (games.home_score < games.visitor_score) THEN games.visitor_team 
    END AS id, teams.class_id, classes.name 
FROM games 
    INNER JOIN teams ON id = teams.id 
    INNER JOIN classes ON teams.class_id = class.id
    WHERE games.complete = 1
```

When I run this query in PHP MyAdmin I get the following error:

```
#1052 - Column 'id' in on clause is ambiguous
```

I am using PDO's execute() so the ?'s represent team id values. I figured since I assigned the result of my CASE statements to id, then I could use it to join the teams table. Can anybody point me in the right direction to fix this error? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't reference a column alias within the `ON` or `WHERE` clauses.  You will have to repeat the `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use either the table name in front of columns present in multiple tables, or use an alias:

```
INNER JOIN teams ON games.id = teams.id
```

Edit: Having said that, it seems that it is in fact a column alias, which you can't do as is:

```
INNER JOIN teams ON
CASE 
    WHEN games.home_team != ? AND (games.home_score > games.visitor_score) THEN games.home_team 
    WHEN games.visitor_team != ? AND (games.home_score < games.visitor_score) THEN games.visitor_team 
END  = teams.id
```

You could also use a subquery first, then match the results without the extra case statement.

```
Select
    sub.id,
    teams.class_id,
    classes.name
from
    (
        SELECT 
            CASE 
            WHEN games.home_team != ? AND (games.home_score > games.visitor_score) THEN games.home_team 
            WHEN games.visitor_team != ? AND (games.home_score < games.visitor_score) THEN games.visitor_team 
            END AS id
        FROM 
            games
        WHERE 
            games.complete = 1
    ) sub
    INNER JOIN teams ON sub.id = teams.id 
    INNER JOIN classes ON teams.class_id = class.id
```

Comment: I ran your examples and realized my logic was off. After fixing it, everything looks good. Which method would you recommend based on performance?

Comment: @RCM8402 Performance will have a *LOT* to do with your database, and isn't something that anyone can simply say "use method x"... Run some testing, smash the database using both methods and see which one holds up better. Change the volume of data in your tables, use whatever method will work best for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple function to make that. It´s working.

```
// get variable
$area = $_GET['area'];

// function
function cases($a) {

    $sel_dash = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sys_dash WHERE area = '$a'");
    $dados = mysql_fetch_assoc($sel_dash);
    $page = $dados['page'];

    return $page;
}

// call function with the variable
$page = cases($area);
```

To test if the value that you get it´s correct you can change the "return" to "echo" and the variable will be write in the code.

The table that i use is:

```
CREATE TABLE `sys_dash` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `area` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `page` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
```

I hope i help !

It´s note CASE class for PHP but have the same function that i need.

Thanks

Doniani